# how to use boost::serialize::make_binary_object against a map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

my intention is to get input from `map<int,std::string>` and create the binary archive which the below code is failing to do , is this the right way of creating it?
And how to know whether the data is correctly archived or not(desirializing using boost)
Do i just need to create a `boost::archive::binary_iarchive oa(oss,1);` and copy it to oss ?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

using namespace std;

class MyConnections
{
  public:
    MyConnections()
    {

       e_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,"ETOTO") ) ;
       e_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,"ETOTO") ) ;

   }

 template<class archive>
void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    using boost::serialization::make_binary_object;
    ar &  boost::serialization::make_binary_object(e_group);
}


  public:
   typedef   map<int,std::string> groups;
   groups  e_group;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const MyConnections conn;
    stringstream oss(ios_base::out|ios_base::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss,1);
    oa << boost::serialization::make_binary_object(conn)
    std::cout<<oss.str;
}
```

Error

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void MyConnections::serialize(archive&, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:29:63: error: cannot convert 'MyConnections::groups {aka std::map<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}' to 'void*' for argument '1' to 'const boost::serialization::binary_object boost::serialization::make_binary_object(void*, std::size_t)'
         ar &  boost::serialization::make_binary_object(e_group);
                                                               ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:42:55: error: cannot convert 'const MyConnections' to 'void*' for argument '1' to 'const boost::serialization::binary_object boost::serialization::make_binary_object(void*, std::size_t)'
    oa << boost::serialization::make_binary_object(conn)
                                                   ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Std output doesn't support random binary output. You'd probably use hex of base64 encoding.

Here's a simplistic approach writing out hex bytes:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>

using namespace std;

class MyConnections
{
    public:
        MyConnections()
        {

            e_group.insert( std::make_pair(1,"ETOTO") ) ;
            e_group.insert( std::make_pair(2,"ETOTO") ) ;

        }

        template<class archive>
            void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
                using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
                ar & make_nvp("Connections", e_group);
            }

    public:
        typedef   map<int,std::string> groups;
        groups  e_group;
};

std::string foo() {
    const MyConnections conn;

    stringstream oss(ios_base::out|ios_base::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss);
    oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("Connections", conn);
    std::string data = oss.str();
    return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string const data = foo();

    for (uint8_t ch : data) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(ch) << " ";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 54 4f 54 4f 02 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 54 4f 54 4f
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/100f32a94fef9cda)</kbd>**

> NOTE: I think the `,1` parameter to the archive constructor was weird. If you're going to pass flags, use the proper enum values.

Comment: sorry for my understanding issues as i am really new to this,  can you please explain me why are u not using make_binary_object here, I would want all the maps data to be a part of binary object and i would also like to desiralize and see if data is correct

Comment: Also , assume that the same serialization fuction works for both binary and  xml format too,  can i use the same serialize function for both xml file and bianry file too ?

Comment: Yes. You have to name the values (make_nvp e.g.) for XML though

Comment: Well, my requirement is to create binary object and xml too , any good approach for doing it ?

Comment: And why is it that you have not considered make_binary_object function? Is that same as make_nvp ?

Comment: @LearningCpp I'm not using `make_binary_object` because I saw no need (do you have large binary objects? I don't see them). Deserialization is a separate task, what code did you write to do it? I answered the question as it was. Your edits changed/expanded it so much, it should probably be a new question (Pro tip: make your question complete before posting)

Comment: You keep [mentioning your requirements as if we are going to do the work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073301/how-to-use-boostserializemake-binary-object-against-a-map/43073750?noredirect=1#comment73231529_43073750). They're your requirements. You can ask about specific steps you get stuck with.

Comment: Yes, the code is a minimal part of it , the xml file that gets created is 2MB actually

Comment: Nope , my intent is to just understand a good approach for both xml and binary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139272/discussion-between-learningcpp-and-sehe).