# C++ Boost binary serialization of pointer constructed from Boost object_pool

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, boost, memory-pool

My application has a class "MyClass". It's objects are being constructed from the Boost Object_pool.

I need to serialized/de serialize this class object via Boost Binary Serialization.

For Serialization -

I take a pointer from the pool, do some operations and serialize it via Boost binary serialization. Everything is good so far.

For De-serialization -

I fetch that serialized buffer and de-serialize it with Boost binary serialization. De-serialization happens successfully, but during the process new memory is being allocated by Boost Serialization mechanism which is not constructed from the Object Pool.
If I allocate the pointer from the pool before de-serialization, the de-serialization allocates the memory on heap again and the track of the memory from the pool is being lost. Hence, I won't be able to reuse this memory allocated by the boost serialization mechanism as it cannot be given back to the object pool because it was not constructed from the pool.

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
  public :
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    MyClass():data(9)
    {
      std::cout << std::endl << "MyClass()" << std::endl ;
    }

template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & data;
  }

~MyClass()
{
}

private :
  int data ;

};


int main()
{
  try
  {

    boost::object_pool<MyClass> pool ;

    // Get object from the Pool.
    MyClass *b = pool.construct();

    // Serialization

    std::stringbuf strbuf;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa( strbuf ) ;
    oa << b ;

    // Deserilaiztion

    //MyClass *a = pool.construct() ;
    MyClass *a ;

    std::stringbuf strbufr(strbuf.str()) ; 
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia( strbufr ) ;

     // This calls the constructor and allocates memory for the pointer.
     // If we allocates this from the pool, new memory is still allocated     
     // and we loose track of the pointer fetched from the pool.   
     ia >> a;
  }
 catch ( boost::archive::archive_exception &e )
 {
   std::cout << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl ;
 }

}
```

What I need -

I want to de-serialize the buffer into the pointer allocated from the pool.

Gone through Boost serialization document and found the concept of Binary object wrappers, however it is resulting in compilation errors.

Main function : -

```
int main()
{
  try
  {

    boost::object_pool<MyClass> pool ;

    MyClass *b = pool.construct();

    std::stringbuf strbuf;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa( strbuf ) ;
    oa << boost::serialization::binary_object(b, sizeof(MyClass) ) ;

    MyClass *a = pool.construct() ;

    std::stringbuf strbufr(strbuf.str()) ;
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia( strbufr ) ;

    ia >> boost::serialization::binary_object(b, sizeof(MyClass) );
  }
  catch ( boost::archive::archive_exception &e )
  {
    std::cout << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl ;
  }

}
```

It gives following compilation errors : -

```
serializationCpy.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:  
serializationCpy.cpp:56:8: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘boost::archive::binary_iarchive’ and ‘boost::serialization::binary_object’)
 ia >> boost::serialization::binary_object(b, sizeof(MyClass) );  
    ^
serializationCpy.cpp:56:8: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/boost_root/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23:0,
             from /home/boost_root/include/boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp:30,
             from /home/boost_root/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:21,
             from /home/boost_root/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp:20,
             from serializationCpy.cpp:1:
/home/boost_root/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:67:15: note: Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator>>(T&) [with T = boost::serialization::binary_object; Archive = boost::archive::binary_iarchive]
 Archive & operator>>(T & t){
           ^
/home/boost_root/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:67:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::serialization::binary_object’ to ‘boost::serialization::binary_object&’
```

Is it the correct way to use serialization with object pool?
Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I just compiled your code with boost vc141 and 1.65.1 and got no compiler errors at all..

Comment: The first version is getting compiled, it's the second main function which is resulting in compilation errors. I am using gcc 4.8.5 and boost 1.65.1, it is giving me compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sourced from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073301/how-to-use-boostserializemake-binary-object-against-a-map) answer, I think it should be

```
ia >> boost::serialization::make_binary_object(a, sizeof(MyClass));
```

or

```
ia & boost::serialization::make_binary_object(a, sizeof(MyClass));
```

instead of `ia >> boost::serialization::binary_object(b, sizeof(MyClass) );`

fixing the other typo's, it'll become:

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    MyClass(int data) :data(data)
    {
        std::cout << "\nMyClass(" << data << ")\n";
    }

    MyClass()
    {
        std::cout << "\nMyClass()\n";
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & data;
    }

    void printData()
    {
        std::cout << "Data = " << data << "\n";
    }
private:
    int data;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::object_pool<MyClass> pool;

        MyClass *b = pool.construct(6);

        std::stringbuf strbuf;
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(strbuf);
        oa << boost::serialization::binary_object(b, sizeof(MyClass));

        MyClass *a = pool.construct();

        std::stringbuf strbufr(strbuf.str());
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(strbufr);

        ia >> boost::serialization::make_binary_object(a, sizeof(MyClass));

        a->printData();
    }
    catch (boost::archive::archive_exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
MyClass(6)

MyClass()
Data = 6
```

[DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/65QeXiZ0Jb7we8Q4)

Comment: I understand that make_binary_object returns const binary_object and its reference can now be used. Program is getting compiled and everything is working as required. However,   `ia & boost::serialization::binary_object(b, sizeof(MyClass)); ` does not work.

Comment: @IranjeetSingh What do you mean with "does not work". What should it do? By the way, could `b` instead of `a` (the object you just create before it) by a typo? And why is `strbufr` not used?

Comment: `b` instead of `a` was a typo. And yes, `strbufr` need not to be used. And `ia & boost::serialization::binary_object(a, sizeof(MyClass));` results in compilation error. The solution is to use `make_binary_object` instead of `binary_object` as it returns const object whose reference can be taken and used by boost serialization class.

Comment: @IranjeetSingh I extended my answer. Is it to your liking?

Comment: Thank you @JHBonarius. Yes, this solution works as intended.

Comment: Hey @JHBonarius. I am trying to go one step ahead in the same program, the pointers which I was trying to serialize and de-serialize are now present in the `std::map<int, MyClass *> MyMap`. Again, the serialization of MyMap as a whole works fine, but getting these pointers from pool during deserialzation is still a challenge for me.

Comment: @IranjeetSingh I suggest you open a new question. You could refer to this question. But new questions belong in a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making a [value-wrapper](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html) or have a custom smart pointer with custom serialization logic.

The `binary_object` way will work but only for POD data types.

Comment: My class will always contains primitive data types only. So, if the binary_object technique will work why is it not compiling. There might be a mistake in the code. Can you please give any advice or suggestion?

Comment: I concur. When I have time later, I will come back to it.

Comment: Hey @sehe I am trying to go one step ahead in the same program, the pointers which I was trying to serialize and de-serialize are now present in the std::map<int, MyClass *> MyMap. Again, the serialization of MyMap as a whole works fine, but getting these pointers from pool during deserialzation is still a challenge for me.